# MySQL LEFT JOIN only 1 row depending on MAX() value

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

### Table 1

```
ID | Name
1    Brain
2    Amy
```

### Table 2:

```
ID | WorkDay    | MissionCode
1    2019-01-01    2360
1    2019-02-01    2470
2    2019-01-01    4470
2    2019-02-01    7210
```

What I want to achieve is, I want to get all table 1 fields and left join on the table 2 but only the latest WorkDay values, like this:

### Expected Result

```
ID | Name | WorkDay    | MissionCode
1    Brain  2019-02-01   2470
2    Amy    2019-02-01   7210
```

What I've tried so far is:

```
SELECT 
    table1.*, t2.WorkDay, t2.MissionCode
FROM 
    table1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        *
     FROM
        table2
     ORDER BY
        WorkDay DESC
     LIMIT 0,1) AS t2
ON
   t2.id = table1.id
```

But it returns NULL values from table2, like this:

```
ID | Name | WorkDay    | MissionCode
1    Brain  NULL         NULL
2    Amy    NULL         NULL
```

I tested the same query adding extra WHERE clause to the inner join's select command and it succedeed.

```
SELECT 
    table1.*, t2.WorkDay, t2.MissionCode
FROM 
    table1
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT
        *
     FROM
        table2
     **WHERE id = 1**
     ORDER BY
        WorkDay DESC
     LIMIT 0,1) AS t2
ON
   t2.id = table1.id
```

And it returns ok, for the first row ofcourse:

```
ID | Name | WorkDay    | MissionCode
1    Brain  2019-02-01   2470
2    Amy    NULL         NULL
```

But I can't use

```
WHERE id = table1.id
```

because MySQL says

```
Unknown column 'table1.id' in 'where clause'
```

So, what is the correct way of this ?

Comment: The [joy of CTE](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=104)

Comment: "get all table 1 fields and left join on the table 2 but only the latest WorkDay values" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When describing a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a simple `JOIN` to `table2`, just put the `MAX(WorkDay)` condition into the `JOIN` condition as a correlated subquery, where you can access the `table1` id value:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id AND
                  t2.WorkDay = (SELECT MAX(WorkDay) 
                                FROM table2 
                                WHERE table2.id = t1.id)
```

Output:

```
ID  Name    ID  WorkDay     MissionCode
1   Brain   1   2019-02-01  2470
2   Amy     2   2019-02-01  7210
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aSacz5HpddJt1dp6nB8qze/0)

Comment: Excuse me, why you didn't use `t2` name in the max query. I mean, like this 
`t2.WorkDay = (SELECT MAX(WorkDay) t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id)`. It is possible, right?

Comment: @fujy the correlated subquery is an independent query that references `table2`, so we can't use `t2` as that is the alias used for the outer query.

Answer (score 0):

This also outputs the same but note @Nick's answer is better
**----------1------------**

```
select
  t1.id,t1.name,t2.workday,t2.Missioncode
  from t1
  left join t2 on 
  t1.id=t2.id
  and t2.workday =(select max(workday) from t2 );
```

**----------2------------**

```
 select t1.id,t1.name,
  (select max(workday) from t2 where t2.id=t1.id)as workday,
  (select max(MissionCode) from t2 where t2.id=t1.id)as missioncode
  from t1;
```